# How can I improve time when using Collections in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

My code is supposed to return the ranking of "Player" if it was added into the ranked array. My code works but it exceeded the time limit. Any advice on what I can do to reduce the time?

```java
public static List<Integer> climbingLeaderboard(List<Integer> ranked, List<Integer> player) {
    // Write your code here

    List<Integer> ranking = ranked.stream().distinct().collect   
                                        (Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> place = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < player.size(); i++){
        ranking.add(player.get(i));
        Collections.sort(ranking);
        Collections.reverse(ranking);
        place.add(ranking.indexOf(player.get(i))+1);
        ranking.remove(player.get(i));
    }
    return place;
    }
}
```

Comment: use TreeMap with rank as key and player as value for O(n) result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort `ranking` *once*, when it's defined, and use `Collections.binarySearch` to find the appropriate position of `player`.

```
List<Integer> ranking = new ArrayList<>(new TreeSet<>(ranked)); // sorts and deduplicates
List<Integer> place = 
    player.stream()
      .map(player -> {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(ranking, player);
        if (index < 0) { index = ~index; }
        return index + 1;
      })
      .toList();
return place;
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not make too much of a difference, but trying doing the sort and reverse at the same time with

```java
Collections.sort(ranking, Collections.reverseOrder());
```